# How to search by part of a synonym

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

I have `products` index with mapping

```
"synonym" : {
    "type" : "synonym",
    "synonyms" : [
        "netbook => laptop"
    ]
}
```

I want to search my products by query "**lapt***" or "**netb***"

Comment: You can check the `prefix` query

Comment: @Val, thanks but question is not how to search by prefix and how to search by part of synonym

Comment: In your example, you examplified prefix search, not infix search, that's why I suggested the prefix query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If searching by `lapt*` works but not `netb*` then you need to change your synonyms filter to this (i.e. replace `=>` by a comma):

```
"synonym" : {
    "type" : "synonym",
    "synonyms" : [
        "netbook, laptop"
    ]
}
```

Using `=>` replaces `netbook` by `laptop` and hence only the latter is indexed. Using a comma, will index both `netbook` and `laptop` and allow you to search for prefixes with both `netb*` and `lapt*`